Debug boot hanging after GRUB
My boot hangs after selecting a boot option from Grub.
If I instead drop into the Grub shell and run:
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-51-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p1
initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.8
boot

then it will always boot successfully. But if I just have GRUB boot it for me, it will hang with a blank screen for a very long time (or forever).
I have not manually messed with my GRUB boot scripts, so they should be whatever the default is.
How can I debug the boot failure and figure out how to get my system booting properly again?
System details:

Framework Laptop 13,  Intel Core Ultra 5 125H
OS: KDE NEON 24.04 with KDE plasma version 6.2.4, Kernel 6.8.0-51-generic


Edit: a few updates based on responses.
I have two kernel options to boot from in GRUB advanced boot options: 6.8.0-51 and 6.8.0-50. Neither of them work if I select them from the GRUB boot menu, but I can successfully boot either one if I do it manually from the GRUB shell in the way I stated above.
I can also successfully boot by going in the GRUB menu to 'Advanced Boot options -> Recovery Mode -> Resume normal boot'. I am not sure why this works when booting just by selecting a normal menu option doesn't.
Output of sudo fdisk -l:
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: <redacted>

Device             Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1   2050048  307202047  305152000 145.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p2 307202048 1953523711 1646321664   785G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3      2048    2050047    2048000  1000M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Edit 2: More further info
Output of sudo cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858
insmod gfxmenu
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/breeze/unifont-bold-16.pf2
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/breeze/unifont-regular-14.pf2
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/breeze/unifont-regular-16.pf2
insmod png
set theme=($root)/boot/grub/themes/breeze/theme.txt
export theme
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
        set gfxpayload="${1}"
        if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
                set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
        else
                set vt_handoff=
        fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if [ ${grub_platform} != pc ]; then
      set linux_gfx_mode=keep
    elif hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'KDE neon 6.2 GNU/Linux' --class kde --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-51-generic root=UUID=c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858 ro reboot=efi quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-51-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for KDE neon 6.2 GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858' {
        menuentry 'KDE neon 6.2 GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.8.0-51-generic' --class kde --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-51-generic-advanced-c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858
                echo    'Loading Linux 6.8.0-51-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-51-generic root=UUID=c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858 ro reboot=efi quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-51-generic
        }
        menuentry 'KDE neon 6.2 GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.8.0-51-generic (recovery mode)' --class kde --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-51-generic-recovery-c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858
                echo    'Loading Linux 6.8.0-51-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-51-generic root=UUID=c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr reboot=efi
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-51-generic
        }
        menuentry 'KDE neon 6.2 GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.8.0-50-generic' --class kde --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-50-generic-advanced-c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858
                echo    'Loading Linux 6.8.0-50-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-50-generic root=UUID=c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858 ro reboot=efi quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-50-generic
        }
        menuentry 'KDE neon 6.2 GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.8.0-50-generic (recovery mode)' --class kde --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-50-generic-recovery-c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858
                echo    'Loading Linux 6.8.0-50-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-50-generic root=UUID=c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr reboot=efi
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-50-generic
        }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi)" --class memtest $menuentry_id_option 'memtest86+' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858
        linux    /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi, serial console)' --class memtest $menuentry_id_option 'memtest86+-serial' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858
        linux   /boot/memtest86+x64.efi console=ttyS0,115200
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
  insmod bli
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
        fwsetup --is-supported
        if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
                menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
                        fwsetup
                }
        fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###
### END /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###


My boot hangs after selecting a boot option from Grub. Which option? What happens if you don't select any and it boots by default? Run sudo fdisk -l, edit the post, copy and paste the output.

@kyodake Any non-recovery mode option will hang, the default option will also hang. I updated the question with some more detail and fdisk output.

Try run this: exec sudo -i --- apt update --- apt install grub-efi-amd64 ---  apt install --reinstall grub-efi ---  update-grub --- reboot

I have tried doing update-grub already to no avail.
Can you explain why you think this will work? It looks like I don't have grub-efi-amd64 installed currently, but I do have grub-efi-amd64-bin installed. I would like to avoid installing redundant packages on my system if possible.

Your initial posting gave the impression that a single kernel version was the culprit. Now, it is about time you try to look into the files in /var/log/.

@Hannu ok where do I look in /var/log/? and what do I look for?

Reinstalling Grub should fix the errors in your menu.

can I reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-bin? or do I need to do the one without the bin which you first suggested?

I just did sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64-bin, sudo apt install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64-bin, and then sudo update-grub. This did not solve the issue, same problem persists.

Run: sudo cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg, edit the message, copy and paste the output.

@kyodake I added the contents of grub.cfg to the post, thanks!

Verify that the UUID c8c41ea3-477c-4fbb-8780-e6aa3e957858 corresponds to /dev/nvme0n1p1. And in /boot/ are: vmlinuz-6.8.0-51-generic and initrd.img-6.8.0-51-generic

Yes, the UUID matches and those files are there (those are the files I use when booting manually from the grub shell, as I said in the original post).
